# EXC_BAD_access code=1 address 0x8

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on xcode 6.1, I am getting this exception and my application get crashed.

> > Thread 1: EXC_BAD_access code=1 address 0x8

and I am redirected to AppDelegate File. 
I get this error , I don't know why? I try to debug this but get no information about the crash. I read something about zombies and enabled it by going to Product->Edit Schema->Diagnostic->Enable Zombie Object. But even after this I didn't get anything helpful.

I try exception breakpoint to check but was not successful. The app terminates as before without giving any exception.

Any way to get out of it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: bad access means that there is some memory violation. You need to provide more information about this issue. Basing on the address that is so small i expect that you somewhere written some to some memory that you shouldn't write.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I just went through all the memory allocation and I got my error.

Comment: @Mohak how to fix this issue please suggest me.